# Globalized WYSIWYG Editors

Tags: localization, editor, wysiwyg

I'm building my own WYSIWYG Editor, and my web application is translated into many languages.  Does anyone outside of the US know, should I translate the button icons as well?

Instead of using the English letters "B" for Bold, "I" for Italic, etc.. should I use the first letter of the translated word for the button icon instead?  Say if the word for "Bold" in Spanish is "Audaz", should I use an "A" instead of a "B" for Bold?

Not sure if this is the best forum, but thought it was worth a shot.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a capital "A" for all buttons, and stylize as required.

> A *A* **A**

Comment: Even for say Asian languages like Chinese, Japanese, Korean?  It seems like if that user doesn't recognize English/Latin alphabet characters, they may not recognize what that character even is.  Korean for Bold is 대담한

Comment: None of those languages really even *use* these styles other than in the context of Roman characters.

Comment: @JohnMcMillion: Well, you could check what Microsoft Office or LibreOffice does. But I'm pretty certain most Asian people using a computer can recognize latin characters.